# Dynamic build a table from json data in angular2

Tags: json, angular, loops, html-table

I can't wrap my head around a looping system I need to make to build up a table from json data. This is what I've got so far (tried some other stuff but I think this illustrates it the best way).

Looping through the headers works fine, it's just the cells I can't get to work.

This is my dummy data:

```
    tableMockData = [
   {
     "header": "TH 1",
      "rows": [
          "TH1 - row1",
          "TH1 -row2",  
          "TH1 - row3", 
          "TH1 - row4" 
      ]
   },
   {
    "header": "TH 2",
     "rows": [
         "TH2 -row1",
         "TH2 - row2",   
         "TH2 - row3", 
         "TH2 - row4",
     ]
  },
  {
    "header": "TH 3",
     "rows": [
      "TH3 -row1",
      "TH3 - row2",  
      "TH3 - row3", 
      "TH3 - row4",
     ]
  },
  {
    "header": "TH 4",
     "rows": [
      "TH4 - row1",
      "TH4 - row2",  
      "TH4 - row3", 
      "TH4 - row4",
     ]
  }
]
```

This is my basic loop as starting point:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let row of tableMockData; let i = index">
      <td>{{row.rows[i]}}</td>
  </tr>
```

This is my outcome:
[image]

This is my desired outcome:
[image]

Can someone point me out in the right direction, I know which cell needs to go where but I simply can't wrap my head around how to loop through it.

Thanks

Update:
here is a stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdoqwb

Answer (score 0):

Update your Html with below code

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <th  *ngFor="let row of tableMockData; let i = index">{{row.header}} 
   </th>
</tr>
<tr  *ngFor="let row of tableMockData; let i = index">
 <td *ngFor="let row1 of row.rows">
   {{row1}}
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You do not properly bind your JSON.

Comment: It seems indeed that with this solution i have multiple header tags so i think it's back to the drawing board. Do you have any idea how to loop through it with remaining the proper table structure?

Comment: The output looks good from the table with your solution. But the html structure doesn't; instead of one <thead> tag with multiple <th> it makes multible <thead> tags in one table body (so kinda 4 mini tables inside one) if that makes sense

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense. Do one thing, make your header separate from JSON

Comment: do you mean seperate the headers from the object with the rows?

Comment: @sirJ edited my answer this gives you proper structure of table

Comment: This is still wrong. The number of rows created depends on the number of columns (the number of objects in the array from OPs example).